# How to do promotion in Rakuten(Magento store)

Tags: magento

We have added all our magento store products in Rakuten. We would like to give promotion(% off) for all of our products. Please explain how we can do this in Rakuten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload New SKU feed with your real list price in MSRP field. Then give %off(if you are givig 35% off for a product whose price is 100, enter 65) for products in Inventory feed 'Price', column. Rakuten automatically calculate % off and will give promotion.